# How to change zoom settings on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, display, external-display

My laptop, via hdmi connects to my TV.

The issue is the TV doesn't fit all the screen. It means the close icon at the top right of windows doesn't show (nor any scroll bar)

Zoom settings do not help. Any other options to reduce the output screen width and height or to add a 5% padding?

Comment: The fix can usually be applied on the TV. It's often disguised under different names and hidden in non-obvious menus. Look for "overscan", "PC mode", "game mode" etc.

Comment: The TV might also have config options for fitting the screen.

Comment: Changing the resolution of the display to the recommended resolution of the TV might also help.

Answer (score -1):

1. Right-click on the Desktop and select **Display** Settings.
2. Make sure you have selected the proper resolution, which matches your TV native resolution.
3. Click on the **Scale and Layout** section and try to change the layout from 100% to 200% or whatever is available.
4. If the issue persists, click on **Advanced scaling Settings**.
5. In the “**Enter a custom scaling Size between 100%-500%**” field, start with entering 100% and gradually improve until you find the right scaling size.
6. Click on **Apply** to save the changes.

Comment: Changing scaling will change how big things on the screen are, but it won't fix the problem of some stuff being outside the visible region.